# How to use Save Hierarchy level in Salesforce reports

Tags: role-hierarchy, hierarchy

Any idea about How to use Save Hierarchy level in Salesforce reports. Cannot see the option to choose this on the report. How do I see data based on roles.

Comment: Hi Guddan, as per my understanding only thing we can do is run dashboard as on the base of Hierarchy one can only run the dashboard as user under one's Hierarchy, here is the link for that functionality https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=dashboards_select_running_user.htm&language=en_US

Answer (score 3):

Not all reports filter on the role hierarchy. Those that do support filtering by hierarchy will automatically provide this option when saving the report using Save or Save As. Those that do not cannot be customized to do so.

Answer (score 2):

This functionality is available on Sales (opportunities), forecast and activities based reporting only.

Answer (score 0):

The biggest place where the hierarchy function is missing, in my experience, is in accounts reports. You cannot, unfortunately, create an accounts report which can be drilled up and down the role hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve this by mirroring it on a custom report type